# If Ability Rip leaves you with 0 HD and 0 Class levels, what happens?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, character-levels, hit-dice

Ability rip causes its target, should they lack supernatural abilities, to permanently 2 class levels, or 2 HD if you've no class levels (what happens if you have exactly 1 class level is addressed [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/160730/what-happens-if-you-have-one-class-level-and-are-ability-ripped)).  Assuming a character with 2 HD and no supernatural abilities, like a typical gnoll, is targetted by Ability Rip the result is a 0 HD gnoll.  Since the typical gnoll also has no class levels and isn't a lycanthrope, this results in a creature with 0 total HD from all sources.  How does that work?  If the creature is also a PC and playing a LA:+0 race like, e.g., an Anthropomorphic Dromedary Camel, how much XP do they need to reach ECL 1?  How much XP does an APL 0 get from a level-appropriate encounter?  Basically, how does 0 HD 0 class level PC life work differently than normal PC life?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The creature dies.

*Ability rip*, shockingly, is poorly written. *Serpent Kingdoms* wholesale is poorly written. Unlike every other source of level loss—mostly negative levels, but also *Savage Species* rituals—*ability rip* fails to explicitly indicate that the creature dies. Very telling that *Serpent Kingdoms* is even less careful than *Savage Species*.

But the creature dying is the only result that is consistent and sensible. The game does not support 0-HD creatures; having HD is one of the things that makes a creature a creature. Even for some RAW theoretical optimization exercise, the best you can get out of this situation is “undefined,” not any particular result you might be hoping for.

Comment: The spell's entry of *Duration: 1 hour/level* makes me queasy. The spell uses *permanently* yet could it mean *permanently* in the *technical* sense as in a [permanent duration](http://dndsrd.net/magicOverview.html#duration)?

Comment: I dunno. It might just remove all of their class/hit dice abilities, reducing their BAB and saving throw bonuses to +0 while simultaneously setting their maximum HP to 0, leaving them permanently disabled until the spell wears off.